# Como obtener el tema actual en que está el teléfono

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, theme

Hola quisiera saber como puedo obtener al iniciar mi app si el teléfono está en modo oscuro o modo claro. Alguna idea?

A ver, la cosa es, usando Android Studio y kotlin para el desarrollo móvil se puede usar `AppCompatDelegate.setDefauldNightMode(modo)` para poner el modo en el que está el teléfono, ya sea oscuro o claro.

Lo que necesito es saber si existe alguna forma en la que pueda saber si al iniciar la app el télefono está en modo oscuro o claro, para así poder controlar estos valores en los temas de la app.

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask],y no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio,  saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir un método que te diga qué modo está activado. Este método devuelve un entero, si su valor es 32 significa que el modo oscuro se encuentra activo.

```
public void modeActivated()
{
    int mode = this.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    if( mode == 32){
        //Lo que deba hacer si el modo oscuro está ACTIVADO.
    }
    if( mode == 16){
        //Lo que deba hacer si el modo oscuro está DESACTIVADO.
    }
}
```

Comment: Es mejor utilizar constantes que literales. [Por ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44170179/13419694).